# linker error "relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol" despite compilation with -fPIC

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, ld, fpic

I'm compiling a c++ program using the command line

```
g++ -c prog.cc -std=c++11 -march=native -fPIC -fopenmp
```

and then try to make a shared object via

```
g++ prog.o -shared -fopenmp -o lib/libprog.so
```

This has always worked. But today I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: prog.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol 
  `_ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_111handle_baseE' can not be used when making a shared
  object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The symbol `_ZTVN12_GLOBAL__N_111handle_baseE` de-mangles to
`vtable for (anonymous namespace)::handle_base`
(`handle_base` is a polymorphic class defined in the anonymous namespace in prog.cc and yes I do call `dynamic_cast<handle_base>()`.)

I'm using gcc version 4.7.0 (GCC) and GNU ld (GNU Binutils; openSUSE 11.1) 2.19. Can anybody help (suggest solutions [other than doing without shared object or the `dynamic cast`])?

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to *define* some *virtual method* for `handle_base`.

Comment: Don't you have to **link** with -fPIC as well?

Comment: @H2CO3 No. (I tried anyway: makes no difference)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko If the method is pure virtual, then you don't defined it. `handle_base` only as one pure virtual method. Making that just virtual and giving a function body does not help.

Comment: Does "g++ -shared prog.cc -std=c++11 -march=native -fPIC -fopenmp -o lib/libprog.so" have the same problem?

Comment: Any luck with this problem? I am stuck with a similar one while trying to compile mozilla JS on my centos 5.3 64 bit machine.

Comment: @Abhishek oops. this has been sorted long ago, but don't ask me how. I now use gcc 4.8, so that may have helped, but perhaps it was a missing library ?? Perhaps I avoided the `dynamic_cast<>()` (most likely).

Comment: We are getting almost the same error and would really like to find a solution. Upgrading the compiler is not an option in our case.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into something similar when upgrading to ubuntu 14.04.   I had to add -fkeep-inline-functions to the source file that defined the 'missing' symbol.  No idea if your problem is similar.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the default visibility hidden for your base class(handle_base). You can do this by -

```
#define VISIBILITY __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
class VISIBILITY handle_base;
```

Comment: (1) I think the `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` is non-standard and not supported in this form by all compilers. (2) why would this solve the problem?

Comment: 1. I don't see anywhere that it says it non-standard. But I will say it says -- "It is best not to use the visibility option for C++ object-oriented programs because of the danger of generating runtime errors that are difficult to debug. Instead, take advantage of the inherent characteristics of C++ object-oriented programs, such as encapsulation, namespaces, inheritance, and other characteristics."
2. As https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility says , the no. 4 may be your case.

Comment: @Robelsharma All `__attribute__`s are GCC extensions. [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) clearly states that these attributes are "C Extensions."