# make file compile error undefined symbol `strtoflt128' error

Tags: compiler-errors, cygwin, ld

I was compiling a make file on my PC. When I ran it, it generates the following error:

> R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `strtoflt128'.

My PC is Windows 8.1 64 bit. I have cygwin64 installed with the following packages; gcc-core4.9.3, gcc-g++ 4.9.3, gcc-fortran 4.9.2-3.

Comment: could you please make this question a little clearer? What application are you trying to compile? (so others might be able to try it, too)... It looks like you don't have the full error here. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779260/linker-error-relocation-r-x86-64-pc32-against-undefined-symbol-despite-compila for a good (similar) question, it might also have your solution!

Comment: I am trying to run make file related to mathlink that can be downloaded from http://www.feynarts.de/mathlink/.

Answer (score 5):

This symbol is provided by [libquadmath](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/strtoflt128.html), so you will need to add `-lquadmath` to your link command.  If it is already there, make sure it comes *after* all object files and static libraries.

Comment: Was not necessary for me under gfortran 6 but now I am seeing this same error under gfortran 7