# W10 + Cygwin + gccV9.2 >>>-----> strtoflt128

Tags: gcc, windows-10, cygwin, gfortran

I compiled and installed gccV9.2 on cygwin and am now getting an error with a simple program that previously compiled and ran without issue.

---

```
$ make
/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/home/rih2wm/gcc-trunk/bin/gfortran.exe -std=gnu -static   -finit-real=-inf  -fcheck=all -ffpe-trap=zero,overflow,underflow   -m64 -lm table.o   -o table.exe
/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/home/rih2wm/gcc-trunk/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.2.0/../../../../lib/libgfortran.a(read.o): In function `_gfortrani_convert_real':
/___packages/gcc/gcc-9.2.0-build/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libgfortran/../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgfortran/io/read.c:175:(.text$_gfortrani_convert_real+0xb7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `strtoflt128'
/cygdrive/C/cygwin64/home/rih2wm/gcc-trunk/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.2.0/../../../../lib/libgfortran.a(read.o): In function `_gfortrani_convert_infnan':
/___packages/gcc/gcc-9.2.0-build/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libgfortran/../../../gcc-9.2.0/libgfortran/io/read.c:251:(.text$_gfortrani_convert_infnan+0xb3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `strtoflt128'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:144: table.exe] Error 1
```

---

`strtoflt128' appears to be missing from libgfortran.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739233/make-file-compile-error-undefined-symbol-strtoflt128-error

Comment: Good eyes, thank you, still no luck.